# Split a block of time if appointments occur within

Tags: php

There are two types of time_block - free, appointment - each time_block has a start_time and end_time.
Say I have five appointment time_blocks and two free time_blocks.

I need to create actual free time_blocks that fill with free time between the appointments, like so:

```
    $appointments = array(
    array(
        'start_time' => 730,
        'end_time' => 830),
    array(
        'start_time' => 830,
        'end_time' => 930),
    array(
        'start_time' => 945,
        'end_time' => 1000),
    array(
        'start_time' => 1045,
        'end_time' => 1100),
    array(
        'start_time' => 1130,
        'end_time' => 1145)
);

$free_time_blocks = array(
    array(
        'start_time' => 900,
        'end_time' => 1000),
    array(
        'start_time' => 1030,
        'end_time' => 1200)
);


// Result should be
$actual_free_time = array(
    array(
        'start_time' => 930,
        'end_time' => 945
    ),
    array(
        'start_time' => 1030,
        'end_time' => 1045
    ),
    array(
        'start_time' => 1100,
        'end_time' => 1130
    ),
    array(
        'start_time' => 1145,
        'end_time' => 1200
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. sort all the appointments by start time
2. free slot start with previous appointment slot end time
3. free slot ends with start of next appointment slot

I would suggest you to used timestamps.

Comment: Thanks, times are just for an example, actual code is using timestamps.
The issue is variable situations - like an appointment starting before the free time, but ending during it etc.

Comment: we can reach to solution, would you please elaborate the requirement in detail?

Comment: The actual free time must be an array of start/end times that represent time between appointments, within the range of the free time. ie. free time - 9-10. appointment 830-930. actual free time - 930-10.
The system needs to handle multiple appointments within the free time range, as well as appointments starting before but ending during, and appointments starting during but ending after. In these cases the actual free time start will be the end of the appointment, or the actual free time end will the start of the appointment, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

Problem solved by trial and error. This is ugly, but it works with every situation I've put it through.

```
<?php
function getAppointmentsInRange($start_time, $end_time){
    $appointments = array(
        array(
            'start_time' => 730,
            'end_time' => 830),
        array(
            'start_time' => 830,
            'end_time' => 930),
        array(
            'start_time' => 945,
            'end_time' => 1000),
        array(
            'start_time' => 1000,
            'end_time' => 1035),
        array(
            'start_time' => 1035,
            'end_time' => 1100),
        array(
            'start_time' => 1105,
            'end_time' => 1125),
        array(
            'start_time' => 1130,
            'end_time' => 1230)
    );

    foreach($appointments as $appointment){
        if($appointment['start_time'] < $end_time && $appointment['end_time'] > $start_time){
            $return[] = $appointment;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}

function setFreeTime($start_time, $end_time){
    echo "Free Time. Start: $start_time, End: $end_time <br/>";
}

$free_time_blocks = array(
    array(
        'start_time' => 900,
        'end_time' => 1000),
    array(
        'start_time' => 1030,
        'end_time' => 1200)
);



foreach($free_time_blocks as $free_time_block){

    // Get appointments with any part falling inside the range (eg. starting before but ending after the start)
    $appointments = getAppointmentsInRange($free_time_block['start_time'], $free_time_block['end_time']);

    $start_time = $free_time_block['start_time'];
    $end_time = $free_time_block['start_time'];

    $finished = false;

    $i = 0;
    foreach($appointments as $appointment){
        echo "trying...<br/>";

        $next = $i + 1;
        $prev = $i - 1;

        if($appointment['start_time'] <= $free_time_block['start_time']){
            echo "case 1 <br/>";
            // If appointment starts before ftb then start ftb at end of appointment, and end at start of next appointment or end of ftb
            if($appointment['end_time'] < $free_time_block['end_time']){
                $start_time = $appointment['end_time'];
            }else{
                $start_time = $end_time;
                break;
            }
            if(isset($appointments[$next])){
                $end_time = $appointments[$next]['start_time'];
            }else{
                $end_time = $free_time_block['end_time'];
            }
        }
        elseif($appointment['start_time'] > $free_time_block['start_time']){
            echo 'case 2 <br/>';
            // If appointment starts during ftb then start ftb at last end time
            // Start time = previous end time

            if($appointment['end_time'] < $free_time_block['end_time']){
                if(isset($appointments[$next])){
                    $end_time = $appointment['start_time'];
                }else{
                    $end_time = $free_time_block['end_time'];
                }
            }elseif($start_time < $appointment['start_time']){
                if(isset($appointments[$prev])){
                    $start_time = $appointments[$prev]['end_time'];
                }
                $end_time = $appointment['start_time'];
            }else{
                break;
            }

        }
        elseif($appointment['start_time'] == $end_time){
            echo "case 3 <br/>";
            if($appointment['end_time'] < $free_time_block['end_time']){
                $start_time = $appointment['start_time'];
            }else{
                break;
            }
            if(isset($appointments[$next])){
                $end_time = $appointments[$next]['start_time'];
            }else{
                $end_time = $free_time_block['end_time'];
            }
        }

        if($start_time != $end_time){
            setFreeTime($start_time, $end_time);
            $start_time = $end_time;
        }

        $i++;
    }
    echo "<hr/>";
}
```